# Spark Direct Stream Kafka order of events

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, hbase, streaming

I have a question regarding reading data with Spark Direct Streaming (Spark 1.6) from Kafka 0.9 saving in HBase.

I am trying to do updates on specific row-keys in an HBase table as recieved from Kafka and I need to ensure the order of events is kept (data received at t0 is saved in HBase for sure before data received at t1 ).

The row key, represents an UUID which is also the key of the message in Kafka, so at Kafka level, I am sure that the events corresponding to a specific UUID are ordered at partition level.

My problem begins when I start reading using Spark.

Using the direct stream approach, each executor will read from one partition. I am not doing any shuffling of data (just parse and save), so my events won't get messed up among the RDD, but I am worried that when the executor reads the partition, it won't maintain the order so I will end up with incorrect data in HBase when I save them.

How can I ensure that the order is kept at executor level, especially if I use multiple cores in one executor (which from my understanding result in multiple threads)?

I think I can also live with 1 core if this fixes the issue and by turning off speculative execution, enabling spark back pressure optimizations and keeping the maximum retries on executor to 1.

I have also thought about implementing a sort on the events at spark partition level using the Kafka offset.

Any advice?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Your question would be more easily answerable if you can show the code you've tried and any specific error responses.

Comment: Spark never guarantees the order of data. It only guarantees its processing. For maintaining the order of data you have to ensure it on your own using stateless or stateful ops.

Comment: @JECarterII The code is not relevant. I am not getting any errors...also currently, the scenario of overlapping events is quite hard for me to test in a prod environment.

Comment: If it's too difficult to test, you're going to be speculating about behavior that you can't measure.  It might be good to consider how you can step back and either improve logging or testing to narrow down the field of inquiry.  As @himanshuIIITian suggests, you may also need to check your basic assumptions about what is going to happen and what is possible.