# Order guarantee by reading a stream with Spark from Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have an ordered Kafka topic with only one partition.
I want to read it from Spark (Spark Streaming or Structured Streaming).
For this purpose I have used this code:

```
spark.readStream.format("kafka") ...
```

To writting in the console to see the result I have used:

```
myStreamName.writeStream.trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("2 seconds")).format("console").outputMode("append").start
```

I have seen in the output all the records of the stream are ordered. But nevertheless I have read in other post Spark doesn't guarantee the order.
See:
[Spark Direct Stream Kafka order of events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50275956/spark-direct-stream-kafka-order-of-events)

And my question is:
Since I'm using **Processing-time** and I read from an **ordered Kafka topic**, can I be sure my output will be always ordered? If not, it's possible to guarantee the ordered output using only one Spark partition (for example applying coalesce() method)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The Kafka consumer* is guaranteed to be ordered, as per the Kafka API contract.

However, any external outputs that you are writing to, may trigger out of order.

I don't really think this is not a problem for most downstream systems... If you are inserting into a database, for example, then you can re-sort by time there. If you have a TSDB, then you're effectively "backfilling" data.

Since you are outputting to the console, that is a blocking call on your IO, and so, reading a batch of Kafka events (in order) from one thread, deserializing, then writing to the console on another thread (ideally in order that they were processed by Spark, but it wouldn't hurt to call to a SparkSQL sort `desc($"timestamp")` here). Once that is complete, then the Kafka offsets can be commmitted, and you continue sequentially reading from Kafka (in order of offsets)... All these events shouldn't have any such race condition where they would be out of order.

Comment: For Stream Processing topics about timestamps, watermarks, re-ordering, etc, maybe a good idea to checkout this book - http://streamingsystems.net/

Comment: cricket_007, good answer. In my use case I can't use an approach with event-time, timestamp and watermarks. The data I have in kafka comes from MySQL (obtained with a chain data capture) and I have realized if I perform some several  insert into... (for example) the operations are so fast that I obtain a repeated timestamp sometimes.

I have used the ForeachWriter to write the data from Spark to Phoenix (jdbc connection) to store it in HBase. And I notice I am storing all the transactions in order. But I need to be completely sure it always be all in order. Do you think in this case will be?

Comment: As soon as you get more than one partition, all bets are off... That network call to perform a write will still block, but I don't have experience with every destination system... And CDC data (Debezium?) comes in with timestamps. I'm not sure I follow... And if you're really concerned about delivery order, I'm only aware of Kafka Connect providing that out of the box (and an Hbase community one does exist, don't use JDBC with Phoenix)

Comment: Yes, I'm using Debezium. And yes, it comes with timestamp but it's not useful for me because as I said, some queries are so fast that the timestamp are duplicated (same timestamp value for two different queries that occur one after the other). I'm using jdbc because I take the exact original query (debezium comes with that option), I parse it (to avoid the 'insert' word transforming it to 'upsert') and I write it to Phoenix. This is for a final university project, then its a good example to show a transformation from SQL to NoSQL.

Comment: Phoenix just has a bad rap with me. Hbase Thrift connections seem to work fine but shouldn't matter either way. But if two Kafka events have the exact same timestamp, then it's hard to say given random chance, which event truly happened "first" on your source database. Thus, if the source cannot destinguish absolute order, then I'm not sure the rest of the pipeline can make up for that

Comment: The official doc says Debezium is idempotent and when send something to Kafka wait until receive the acks. After receive the acks can continue sending. Then I imagine the kafka topic (which have only one partition) like an ordered by arrival queue. To reading the strem I think Spark uses only one partition because there is only one partition in the kafka topic and is reading the ordered kafka topic secuencially in order by arrival. this is the code for writing: writeStream.trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("3 seconds")).foreach(writer).start() and the foreach send it (I use ProcessingTime)

Comment: And with ProcessingTime the foreach write in the same order the events arrived. Maybe I'm wrong about how all of this works but I can say I have printed what is happening into the sink and I see the process method process the queries in order, parses it and send the query to Phoenix. In the debezium messages there is an optional GTID field (which give me an unique transaction identifier) but It is not being used anywhere in this pipeline to ordering. I started learning Kafka and Spark 5 months ago so I am not an expert. Maybe all the magic occurs when using only one partition.I dont know

Comment: Yes, as explained, having one partition preserves order for all Kafka related tasks. Spark likely buffers and writes these records in the order they are received, but without knowing the internals of how this works, I cannot say 100% for sure